# How to display data into second column of a table in jsp by using jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I would like to display a table in jsp which contains two columns (Date , Rating). Here is my jsp code:

```
<table id="results" ALIGN="center" BORDER="1" WIDTH="50%">
        <tr>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>Rating</th>
        </tr>
          <c:forEach var="sDate" items="${currentSessionSelectDate}">
                <tr>
                   <td><center>${sDate}</center></td>
                </tr>
          </c:forEach>
          <c:forEach var="monthRating" items="${currentSessionMonthRating}">
                <tr>
                   <td><center>${monthRating}</center></td>
                </tr>
          </c:forEach>
</table>
```

"sDate" is a dataset that retrieved from database which is going to be displayed under "Date" column while "monthRating" is the dataset for "Rating" column.

How can I make the "monthRating" to be displayed under "Rating" column? Now all the data are being displayed under "Date" column.
thanks if you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to make one list instead of two lists than it would be better to iterate it in table. But if not possible for you than try this code may this help :)

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Rating</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <table>
                    <c:forEach var="sDate" items="${currentSessionSelectDate}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${sDate}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </td>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <c:forEach var="monthRating" items="${currentSessionMonthRating}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${monthRating}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! :D Do you know how can I make the query which select two values (Date , Rating) from a table and pass them to jsp within one list? That's why I separate two lists. :( @NaMaN

Comment: Yes, you can fetch as many column values from table as long as values are present in table. `select Date,Rating from <TableName>;` And to pass single list you need to make bean with getter and setter for that table;

Comment: Now I have a bean with the values in it, so how to get these values in jsp by using jstl?

Comment: Here is good example try it: http://javaknowledge.info/jsp-servlet-jstl-and-mysql-simple-crud-application/

Comment: Thanks @NaMaN! You gave a very useful information! :D